# How to join different tables with same propriety tables?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Which would be the best solution to join 4 different tables with X tables that has to be the same for the 4 tables?

Let's presume we have 2 tables `MENU` and `PLATES` each of that tables could be joined with tables like `IMAGES`, `DESCRIPTIONS`, `ALLERGENS` and other tables that will give some properties to `MENU` and `PLATES`

Which would be the best practise to join those property tables with the main ones?

Should i create in each property table a column for each main table as foreign key? Like this:

```
+----+--------------+--------+----------+
| ID | DESC         | ID_MEN | ID_PLATE |
+----+--------------+--------+----------+
| 1  | PIZZE        | 1      |          |
+----+--------------+--------+----------+
| 2  | CHICKEN SOUP |        | 4        |
+----+--------------+--------+----------+
```

Or should i create a intersect table for each main table that has FK for each propriety table like this:

```
+--------+---------+-----------+
| ID_MEN | ID_DESC | ID_IMAGES |
+--------+---------+-----------+
| 1      | 2       | 3         |
+--------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: Can you help me understand the difference between a `MENU` and a `PLATES` record?  In my mind those seem to be the same thing but I would imagine you have a more granular definition, which is why they are 2 separate tables.  Also, are the other "attributes" (`IMAGES`, `DESCRIPTIONS`, `ALLERGENS`) a 1-to-1 relationship or is a `MENU`/`PLATES` object allowed to have multiple of each?  (I am going to guess that `DESCRIPTIONS` may be a 1-to-1 where the others could be a 1-to-many relationship)

Comment: @KirkSaunders the `MENU` / `PLATES` could have multiple attributes so 1-to-many, the tables are separate as i'm working on a yet created database where a `MENU` has almost same columns of `PLATES` but are separated as some columns are different and actually the `PLATES` belong to`MENU` but each `PLATE` or `MENU` could have 1 or more `images` 1 or more `description` (different language) and different `allergens` like `PLATE` "pizza" could have `allergens` "pasta", "pomodoro" or a `MENU` could have some generic allergens

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you for that information.  One more question, does that mean that the `PLATES` is a child table to `MENU`?  Or are they just separate tables which hold similar but different elements?

Comment: @KirkSaunders in this case `PLATES` are child of menu but there is another table `ITEMS` that is the same of `PLAYES` which hold similar elements but doesn't belong to any `MENU` (the table `ITEMS`) should have same proprieties as `MENU` and `PLATES` like images etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a combination of the two solutions you provided is what you are looking for.

I think specifically what you are wanting to do is create a separate `table` for each of your attributes (`IMAGE`, `DESCRIPTION`, etc...).  Then you will create a `bridge table` between your objects and their attributes.  This allows you to have tables for each of your attributes.  That way you have those items `normalized`.  The `bridge table` then allows you to maintain the 1-to-many relationship between each of your objects and its attributes.  The downside with this plan is you will end up having a lot of tables as your attributes increase or your object types increase.  But the separation of data elements will allow you to keep the data integrity much better.

There is another solution utilizing a generic `OBJECT-ATTRIBUTE` table that allows you to maintain everything now and in the future in one place with a little bit of effort.  There is a great [article provided by Red Gate](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/ten-common-database-design-mistakes/) which recommends against this method.  I would check out the "One table to hold all domain values" section.

Here is what I think you are looking for.  Assuming:

1. `PLATE` is a child table of `MENU`
2. `ITEM` is a child table of `PLATE`
3. The only 3 attributes you currently have are `DESCRIPTION`, `ALLERGEN` and `IMAGE`

Let me know if there are any questions or if this solution does not take care of everything you are looking for.

[image: Possible ER Diagram]

Comment: First of all thank you! Actually that was by biggest fear that there will be lot of tables and assuming that the "property" tables will be up to 8 yea..  but as you said it's important to keep the data integrity so i'd go for that bridge table solution

Comment: This smells like "over-normalization".

Comment: @RickJames, I am starting to realize I might "over-normalize" as a general tendency.  What changes would you make?